# List of All OSX Developer Utilities?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, system, developer-tools

I'm new to OSX Development and Apple system frameworks/apis/tools.

In the process of learning, I've stumbled upon a handful of "secret" utility programs that are extremely helpful to developers but have mixed levels of visibility/googleability/shell completion (e.g. `kextutil`, `lsregister`, `auvaltool`)

Is there a listing of all these "secret" developer utilities somewhere?

Comment: Can't you just do `man kextutil`?

Comment: man auvaltool also works. but man lsregister doesn't.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer: sure—that's not my question.

Comment: @pje I answered it before you edited question.  In that case, try [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/)? (Though it's a very long list)

Comment: to the downvoters: any explanatory comments would be helpful. If I know that the program exists I can run `man program`. That's not the point. This question is about discovery of existing—but unknown to me—developer utilities. If they're listed somewhere obvious, I'd love to know where.

Comment: @pje There's a link in my previous comment

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer: I mean, that's the best I've seen. :) I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/) of developer functions and tools

Comment: Also admin tools, a few file formats, etc. Manpages are categorized by section: sections 1 and 8 are command-line tools, 2 and 3 are APIs, section 5 is file formats, and section 4 is about special files, such as stdin, stdout, the random device, and so on.

Comment: "Mac OS X contains a number of 'secret' debugging facilities, including environment variables, preferences, routines callable from GDB, and so on. This technotes describes these facilities. If you're developing for Mac OS X, you should look through this list to see if you're missing out on something that will make your life easier." — via Technical Note TN2124 (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391)